# Python String split with multiple regex

Tags: python, html, regex

Hi I have Python String as shown below:

```
<html><table border = 1><tr><td>JDICOM</td><td>Thu Sep 16 10:13:34 CDT 2010</td></tr></html>
```

From above string I am interested in two words

```
JDICOM
Thu Sep 16 10:13:34 CDT 2010
```

I tried `find`, `findall`, `split` but it did not help because of multiple regex.

I am quite new to python. If anyone knows please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Statutory Warning:** don't use regular expressions to parse (X)HTML. You are much better off using a parser such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

For e.g.

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """<html><table border = 1><tr><td>JDICOM</td><td>Thu Sep 16 10:13:34 CDT 2010</td></tr></html>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> for each in soup.findAll(name = 'td'):
 print each.contents[0]


JDICOM
Thu Sep 16 10:13:34 CDT 2010
>>>
```

That said, here is a regular expression to do the same thing. Warning: this will stop working if the markup is irregular.

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('<td>(.*?)</td>', re.I | re.S)
>>> for each in pattern.findall(html):
 print each


JDICOM
Thu Sep 16 10:13:34 CDT 2010
>>>
```